# is it possible to create .mobileprovision file from free apple user id?

Tags: ios, apple-id, mobileprovision

I am new to iOS app development.

I need to create .mobile provision file and for this I need an apple user id.

I have free user account .

now is it possible to create a .mobileprovision file ?

Answer (score 1):

No, to create a provisioning profile, you need to sign up for the iOS developers program ($99/year)